# How to bind or loop random background images to text

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have images in a folder and i want to randomize the images to display as full background images whiles displaying the text description of the current background image been displayed? The code is show below.

```
<?php
  function displayBackground()
   {
   $dir = 'control/uploads/image/home_bg/';
   $cnt = 0;
   $bgArray= array();

  /*if we can load the directory*/
  if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {

  /* Loop through the directory here */
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

  $pathToFile = $dir.$entry;
  if(is_file($pathToFile)) //if the files exists 
  { 

    //make sure the file is an image...there might be a better way to do this
    if(getimagesize($pathToFile)!=FALSE)
    {
      //add it to the array
      $bgArray[$cnt]= $pathToFile;
      $cnt = $cnt+1;

    }

  } 

} 
//create a random number, then use the image whos key matches the number
$myRand = rand(0,($cnt-1)); 
$val = $bgArray[$myRand];

  }
  closedir($handle);
  echo('"'.$val.'"');

  }


  ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [_How do I ask a good question?_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have tried using php to randomize the background images but dont know how to output the text description for the current image been displayed.

Comment: So then show what you've tried, and where you are stuck. No one can help you with code that they can not see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disagree with Phillip's solution. Using a path as a file name and have a text file for it can produce many files. Putting information into one easily accessible place for data with same structure is the best practice.

You need to store the information in somewhere (a file or a database table), and get the corresponding text description. [You can also hard-code it in your code, but I don't recommend that]

If you don't have many image files, I suggest that you can just put the information into a .json file, with a format similar like this:

```
[{"file":"control/uploads/image/home_bg/image1.jpg","description":"This is the first image"},
{"file":"control/uploads/image/home_bg/image2.jpg","description":"This is the second image"}]
```

Then in your php code you can just do `json_decode(file_get_contents($path_of_this_json_file));` and get an array of the information.

If you want to randomly display these, just use a php random function to select an element from the array and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the text decriptions stored somewhere, indexed by the file name.

This can be either different `.txt` files named `[file-name-of-image].txt` or you can use an array where the indexes are the file names and the values the descriptions.

In that way, you only need the image file name to get the description and display it.